# Regular Expression For Password Field

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for a password field that:

- Must have 1 number
- Must have 1 letter (uppercase)
- Must have 1 letter (lowercase)
- Must be at least 8 characters in length
- Must only contain alpha and numeric characters

So far I have:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,})
```

This meets most of my conditions above. But how can I limit this to only allow alpha numeric characters.

Comment: The last requirement is quite unconventional for passwords.

Comment: Moreover, the last requirement forces users into using weaker passwords, and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: [Don't. Just don't.](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: @Antti your link kinda says the opposite, doesn't it?

Comment: Each and every of these rules would disallow using `'correct horse battery staple'` as a passphrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of `.` and anchor your regex:

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the base at the end:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[^\W_]{8,})
```

This solution expects your regex engine to be **anchored**. If not, anchor them with `^$`.

`[^\W_]` is negated character class. It asserts that this character is not a word character or `_`.

As word characters covers alphanumeric characters and underscores, this double-negated character class shorthand `[^\W_]` is well-used for these scenarios.

You can use `[[:alnum:]]` as well, if your regex engine supports ascii classes.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/hX6gL8/1)!